# Block outgoing SSH connection from server

Tags: linux, ssh

**Background**

I got a service that connects to a third-party SFTP site to pull files. The third-party has a system that when certain users try to connect, it automatically blocks the incoming IP.
Someone is doing some connection attempts while using the forbidden user as due to be a legacy system, any user gets to the system as root. Whenever this individual tries the sftp root@remote-site he/she just breaks a couple of applications that rely on the same remote SFTP.

**Question**
Is there any way with SSH to block this outgoing connection for a specific user@site?
Match rule is for sshd_config which is basically incoming. Is there an equivalent for ssh client?

Comment: use `~user/.ssh/config` to redirect outgoing `ssh somehost` to 127.0.0.1. (I am not sure this will solve Y part of the XY-Problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Match* rule for sshd_config works also for ssh_config, and in particular the global `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file which you can edit to contain:

```
Match host site user root
 Hostname DontDoThat
```

This will replace the hostname when you do an ssh or sftp:

```
$ sftp root@site
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

$ sudo sftp site
ssh: Could not resolve hostname dontdothat: Name or service not known
```

Of course, the user's `~/.ssh/config` file can still override this setting.

You might want to log information about the person doing the sftp by adding to the Match line a call of a script (that must exit 0), eg `exec "/bin/mylogger somearg..."` (don't use single quotes).

Comment: This is great. At least until we identify the user making the "malicious" outbound connection.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `iptable`, for example:

Block outgoing `ssh` connection for 192.168.1.0/24 subnet

```
 iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24  -p tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

Then verify

```
ssh -v 192.168.1.6
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.6 [192.168.1.6] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.6 port 22: **Connection refused**
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.6 port 22: **Connection refused**
```

Comment: Thanks but this blocks all connectios. Not what I am looking for. If ssh is done with ssh root@remote-site it gets blocked. if ssh user1@remote-site needs to work. The suggested solution blocks all.

Comment: @BitsOfNix "outgoing SSH connection from server" means block the whole  connection! To block specific users. You can edit `ssh_d config` and add any user name you want to block under DenyUsers. Just do `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, then under `DenyUsers` add the user name you want to block. Let's say you want to block user mark then add `DenyUsers mark`. Let me know if this work or not so we can help further ;-)

Comment: @user88036 he wants to block all outgoing connections, not incoming connections.

Answer (score 1):

You can always allow outgoing SSH connection with iptables "user" module:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0  -p tcp --destination-port 22 -m owner --uid-owner {USERNAME} -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j DROP
```

This will block all outgoing ssh connections, but allow {USERNAME} to perform it.